# TCA "internal_type" => file with autocomplete function

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a question about the TYPO3 (6.2) TCA and autocomplete. I have already have that in use for tables. With success. Now i have a case with an non table - folder full of PDF files...

Is that possible to handle with files within an upload folder too? I tried like that... Autocompletefield comes but it´s showing "no results found"...  Any ideas related to that?

```
    'file' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:src_products/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_srcproducts_domain_model_files.file',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_srcproducts',
            'allowed' => 'gif,jpg,pdf',
            'disallowed' => 'php',
            'size' => 5,
            'wizards' => array(
                'uproc' => array(
                    'type' => 'userFunc',
                    'userFunc' => 'user_class->user_TCAform_procWizard',
                ),
                'suggest' => array(
                    'type' => 'suggest',
                ),
            )

        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the [official documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/AdditionalFeatures/WizardsConfiguration/Index.html) (search for "suggest"):

> This renders an input field next to the selector of group-type fields (when internal_type is db) or of select-type fields (using foreign_table).

So, it seems to be impossible to use this wizard for files and folders.